# Cheerio - Node js scraping number of reviews and stars

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to take links from yelp and google places and scrape their star rating along with the number of reviews they have. I've managed to get the yelp URL scraper to work properly but when I tried to use the same methods for the Google URL I either get empty strings returned for the .text(); or an undefined .attr();

**This is the HTML I'm attempting to scrape**

```
<div class="review-score-container">
  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <span style="font-size:32px;margin-right:11px" class="rtng" aria-
    hidden="true">4.9</span>
    <g-review-stars>
      <span class="_pxg _Kxg" aria-label="Rated 4.9 out of 5,">
        <span style="width:100px"></span>
      </span>
    </g-review-stars>
    <div style="display:inline;font-size:15px;margin-left:11px">
      <span class="_Mnc _yz" style="white-space:nowrap">96 reviews</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*This can also be found in the googleURL link below*

```
var request = require('request')
var cheerio = require('cheerio')

var yelpURL = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/yo-way-gardena'
var googleURL = 'https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&ei=9UafWtn0IaiZjwTXrJn4CQ&q=yo-way&oq=yo-way&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i67k1l2j0i30k1l5.4447.5658.0.5873.15.8.0.0.0.0.152.868.3j5.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..11.4.450...33i160k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.DnG3LoY6RC0&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=38062739,-95056704,2059057&tbm=lcl&rldimm=5797977981249230753&ved=0ahUKEwi1g6eHjtnZAhUm54MKHdxpDVoQvS4IRTAA&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9#lrd=0x80c2caa3a184dc3d:0x50768e4143e597a1,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5797977981249230753;mv:!1m3!1d4716380.17730953!2d-95.05670475!3d37.9292408!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1185!2i281!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9';

if (yelpURL) {
  request(yelpURL, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      var reviews = $('span[class="review-count rating-qualifier"]').first().text();
      var stars = $('img[class="offscreen"]').attr('alt');

      console.log('Number of reviews : ' + reviews);
      console.log('Business Assessment : \n\t    ' + stars + '\n');
    }
  });
}
if(googleURL) {
  request(googleURL, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      var reviews = $('span[class="_Mnc _yz"]').first().text();
      var stars = $('span[class="rtng"]').first().text();
      //var stars = $('span[class="_pxg _Kxg"]').attr('aria-label');

      console.log('Number of reviews : ' + reviews);
      console.log('Business Assessment : ' + stars);
    }
  });
}
```

I attempted to scrape the rating from the _pxg class from its aria-label attribute and just getting to "4.9" from the rtng class and they only return undefined or empty strings. As for review numbers, the only place to get that is the _Mnc class and it always just returns an empty string. I know google removed `user_rating_total` from their Google Places API otherwise, I would've just used that. My guess is that Google doesn't want people easily scrapping their website or I'm just really new to this and missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `request` is that it can't execute javascript rendered data. Try using a headless browser instead. [Nightmare](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) is a great one. You make a call using nightmare instance then pass the html code to your cheerio. Here is the sample:

```
nightmare
    .viewport(1280, 800)
    .goto(url)

    //do something in the chain to go to your desired page.

   .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').outerHTML)
   .then(function (html) {
      cheerio.load(html);
      // do something in cheerio
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working with your solution. The code seems to work as intended dozens of times in a row, but will randomly return 'undefined' or empty strings even though I haven't altered any code. Fortunately for my purposes I'd only need to have this program run about once a week, but I feel like it could just be google blocking me after x amount of requests.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any browser automation to get your information because it can get from a simple request, which needs fewer resources to do this. To fix your code, you just need to add `User-Agent` headers to your request to prevent blocking from Google/Yelp. [Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-and-Yelp-places-rating-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js).

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
  },
};

const yelpURL = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/yo-way-gardena";
const googleURL =
  "https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&ei=9UafWtn0IaiZjwTXrJn4CQ&q=yo-way&oq=yo-way&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i67k1l2j0i30k1l5.4447.5658.0.5873.15.8.0.0.0.0.152.868.3j5.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..11.4.450...33i160k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.DnG3LoY6RC0&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=38062739,-95056704,2059057&tbm=lcl&rldimm=5797977981249230753&ved=0ahUKEwi1g6eHjtnZAhUm54MKHdxpDVoQvS4IRTAA&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9#lrd=0x80c2caa3a184dc3d:0x50768e4143e597a1,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5797977981249230753;mv:!1m3!1d4716380.17730953!2d-95.05670475!3d37.9292408!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1185!2i281!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9";

function getYelpResult() {
  return axios(yelpURL, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(({ data }) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const reviews = $('.css-1fdy0l5').first().text();
    const stars = $('.css-1fdy0l5').first().parent().parent().find("span > div").attr("aria-label");

    console.log("Yelp Cheerio result:")
    console.log("Number of reviews : " + reviews);
    console.log("Business Assessment : \n\t    " + stars + "\n");
  });
}
function getGoogleResult() {
  return axios(googleURL, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(({ data }) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const reviews = $(".HypWnf").text().replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    const stars = $('.HypWnf').closest('.MvDXgc').find(".YDIN4c").text();
    
    console.log("------------------")
    console.log("Google Cheerio result:")
    console.log("Number of reviews : " + reviews);
    console.log("Business Assessment : " + stars);
  });
}

getYelpResult();
getGoogleResult();
```

Output:

```json
------------------
Google result:
Number of reviews : 359
Business Assessment : 4.8
Yelp result:
Number of reviews : 967 reviews
Business Assessment : 
        5 star rating
```

Alternatively, you can do this using [Google Local "Places" Results API](https://serpapi.com/local-results) and [Yelp Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/yelp-search-api) from SerpApi. It's a free API with 100 searches per month.

The difference is that you don't have to figure out which selectors to use and then maintain the parser over time. All the information is immediately available to you, you just need to process the JSON file. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Example code to integrate:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY); //your API key from serpapi.com

const query = "yo-way"; // what we want to search
const location = "Gardena, California, United States"

const paramsYelp = {
  engine: "yelp",                      // search engine
  find_desc: query,                    // search query
  find_loc: location,                  // parameter defines from where you want the search to originate
};

const paramsGoogle = {
  engine: "google",                   // search engine
  q: query,                           // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",        // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                           // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                           // parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  tbm: "lcl",                         // parameter defines the type of search you want to do
  location: location,                 // parameter defines from where you want the search to originate
};

const getYelpRating = function ({ organic_results }) {
  const place = organic_results.find((el) => el.title === "Yo-Way Eatery")
    
  console.log("From Yelp:")
  console.log("Number of reviews : " + place.reviews);
  console.log("Business Assessment : " + place.rating);
};

const getGoogleRating = function ({ local_results }) {
  const place = local_results.find((el) => el.title === "YO WAY SANDWICH SHOP")
    
  console.log("From Google:")
  console.log("Number of reviews : " + place.reviews);
  console.log("Business Assessment : " + place.rating);
};

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  });
};

function getResults = () => {
  console.log("------------------")
  console.log('SerpApi results:')
  getJson(paramsYelp).then(getYelpRating);
  getJson(paramsGoogle).then(getGoogleRating);
};

getResults();
```

Output:

```
------------------
SerpApi results:
From Yelp:
Number of reviews : 967
Business Assessment : 5
From Google:
Number of reviews : 359
Business Assessment : 4.8
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi